# Хочу написать либу которая будет работать на linux и windows

Tags: c++, linux, c, windows, lib

Моя либа будет использовать системные библиотеки, так как у linux и unix они разные, предлагается сделать следующее. Написать 2 cpp файла  и 1 h файл. Можно ли сделать что бы в одной системе либа собиралась с первым cpp файлом в котором код под linux, а в другой системе второй cpp файл под windows.

Comment: Можно. Можно даже с одним с двумя кодами.

Comment: Подобное можно реализовать двумя способами: в первом случае через ifdef (как уже было написано), в током случае у вас должен быть 1 cpp файл. Можно же реализовать это на уровне системы сборки - тогда у вас будет 2 cpp файла а в системе сборки будут выбираться (в зависимости от системы) исходники для сборки

Comment: Спасибо, можете описать как делать вторым способом, или где это можно посмотреть ?

Comment: Смотря что именно вы собираетесь использовать из системных функций, можно использовать чужие библиотеки. https://directory.fsf.org/wiki/Commoncpp

Answer (score 6):

Можно сделать. но лучше делать знаете как? использовать define в коде. типа такого.

```
int get_parameters ( ) {
  int i = 0;
#ifdef __WIN32__
  ...
#elseif __LINUX__
  ...
#endif
  return i;
}
```